# Spring data date between query

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a query like below:

```
select * from Products p where ? between  p.effctDate and p.expDate
```

Can I translate the above query to a spring data jpa query method? Like for example:

```
findByProductId(productId)
```

or I only have to use **@Query** or a **Named query** to handle such types of queries. I tried searching here first before asking the question as well as spring data site but did not find any solution. any help is appreciated.

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve? why aren't the `@Query` and `Named` suitable?

Comment: Hi Andrew, its not a question of suitability as both `@Query` and `Named` suitable for me. I just wanted to know if it is possible to translate the given query via a query method. :)

Comment: I didn't get the query. There is a column `effctDate` which should be in range of `[A, B]` and a `expDate` in the `[A, B]`, is that right?

Comment: No not like that, the `?` is my input parameter which should be between `effctDate` and `expDate` for example: `select * from Products p where '08/18/2017' between  p.effctDate and p.expDate`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use the following query:

```
Date date = //Input date
List<Product> = findByEffctDateAfterAndExpDateBefore(date, date);
```

Note that you have to enter `date` twice to match both 'where' clauses. This is under the assumption you are using `Date` objects, not literal `String`s.

See [JPA Repositories](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.1.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html) Table 2.3 for more info.

Comment: oh ok! so this is how we have to handle it. I did came across after and before query but never thought of joining them will do the trick. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can try to use something like below :

List findAllByDateApprovedBetween(String dateApprovedFrom, String dateApprovedTo);

It translates to :

Hibernate: select applicatio0_.id as id1_1_, applicatio0_.date_approved as date_app4_1_ from application applicatio0_ where (applicatio0_.date_approved between ? and ?)

Comment: Thanks !, this answer should be at the top is the best solution

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this trick:

```
select 
    p 
from 
    Product p 
where 
    (?1 = 'field1' and p.field1 between p.effctDate and p.expDate)
    or (?1 = 'field2' and p.field2 between p.effctDate and p.expDate)
    or (?1 = 'field3' and p.field3 between p.effctDate and p.expDate) 
    or (?1 = 'field4' and p.field4 between p.effctDate and p.expDate) 
    ...
```

But this is not the best approach IMO...

To build dynamic queries you can use thees ones:

- [Specifications](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications)
- [Query by Example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example)
- [Querydsl Extension](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#core.extensions.querydsl)